# iOS - Understanding my symbolicated crash report (help needed)

Tags: ios, cordova, debugging, ionic-framework, crash-reports

My app is rejected from the iOS store because the app is terminated after user log in. I'm not able to reproduce the problem (local devices, TestFlight), it looks like it only happens when the app is running in production.

I have symbolicated the crash report that I got from the App Store review team. I understand that a abort() is called ontThread 0. But I have a hard time understanding the crash report. I'm new to crash reports so I appreciate the help!

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x192e2efe0 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x191890538 objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                  0x192e35ef4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140
3   CoreFoundation                  0x192e32f54 ___forwarding___ + 916
4   CoreFoundation                  0x192d2ed4c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   appname                         0x1000c9ce4 -[PushPlugin setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:] (PushPlugin.m:573)
6   appname                         0x10015d130 -[CDVCommandQueue execute:] + 504
7   appname                         0x1000e6d98 -[CDVWKWebViewEngine handleCordovaMessage:] (CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:427)
8   appname                         0x1000e6c40 -[CDVWKWebViewEngine userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:] (CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:413)
9   appname                         0x1000e7b98 -[CDVWKWeakScriptMessageHandler userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:] (CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:601)
10  WebKit                          0x19c729590 ScriptMessageHandlerDelegate::didPostMessage(WebKit::WebPageProxy&, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, WebCore::SerializedScriptValue&) + 196
11  WebKit                          0x19c6c8c48 WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::didPostMessage(IPC::Connection&, unsigned long long, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&) + 176
12  WebKit                          0x19c6cb0c0 void IPC::handleMessage<Messages::WebUserContentControllerProxy::DidPostMessage, WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy, void (WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::*)(IPC::Connection&, unsigned long long, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&)>(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&, WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy*, void (WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::*)(IPC::Connection&, unsigned long long, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&)) + 156
13  WebKit                          0x19c4fbda4 IPC::MessageReceiverMap::dispatchMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 120
14  WebKit                          0x19c6a4830 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 32
15  WebKit                          0x19c4c1c8c IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Decoder> >) + 164
16  WebKit                          0x19c4c4484 IPC::Connection::dispatchOneMessage() + 232
17  JavaScriptCore                  0x19769fff4 WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 172
18  JavaScriptCore                  0x1976a02cc WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
19  CoreFoundation                  0x192ddd42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
20  CoreFoundation                  0x192ddcd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
21  CoreFoundation                  0x192dda9a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
22  CoreFoundation                  0x192d0ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
23  GraphicsServices                0x194774074 GSEventRunModal + 100
24  UIKit                           0x198fbe058 UIApplicationMain + 208
25  appname                         0x1000b2b78 main (main.m:32)
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x191d1959c start + 4


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000191e29014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000191ef3264 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000191d9d9c4 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001918691b0 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000191882c04 default_unexpected_handler() + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000191890820 _objc_terminate() + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019187f5d4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019187eef8 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019189066c _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 0
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192e35ef4 __methodDescriptionForSelector + 0
10  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192e32f54 ___forwarding___ + 916
11  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192d2ed4c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
12  appname                         0x00000001000c9ce4 -[PushPlugin setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:] (PushPlugin.m:573)
13  appname                         0x000000010015d130 -[CDVCommandQueue execute:] + 504
14  appname                         0x00000001000e6d98 -[CDVWKWebViewEngine handleCordovaMessage:] (CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:427)
15  appname                         0x00000001000e6c40 -[CDVWKWebViewEngine userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:] (CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:413)
16  appname                         0x00000001000e7b98 -[CDVWKWeakScriptMessageHandler userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage:] (CDVWKWebViewEngine.m:601)
17  WebKit                          0x000000019c729590 ScriptMessageHandlerDelegate::didPostMessage(WebKit::WebPageProxy&, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, WebCore::SerializedScriptValue&) + 196
18  WebKit                          0x000000019c6c8c48 WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::didPostMessage(IPC::Connection&, unsigned long long, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&) + 176
19  WebKit                          0x000000019c6cb0c0 void IPC::handleMessage<Messages::WebUserContentControllerProxy::DidPostMessage, WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy, void (WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::*)(IPC::Connection&, unsigned long long, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&)>(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&, WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy*, void (WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::*)(IPC::Connection&, unsigned long long, WebKit::FrameInfoData const&, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&)) + 156
20  WebKit                          0x000000019c4fbda4 IPC::MessageReceiverMap::dispatchMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 120
21  WebKit                          0x000000019c6a4830 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&) + 32
22  WebKit                          0x000000019c4c1c8c IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Decoder> >) + 164
23  WebKit                          0x000000019c4c4484 IPC::Connection::dispatchOneMessage() + 232
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000019769fff4 WTF::RunLoop::performWork() + 172
25  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001976a02cc WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*) + 36
26  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192ddd42c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192ddcd9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192dda9a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
29  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000192d0ada4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
30  GraphicsServices                0x0000000194774074 GSEventRunModal + 100
31  UIKit                           0x0000000198fbe058 UIApplicationMain + 208
32  appname                         0x00000001000b2b78 main (main.m:32)
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000191d1959c start + 4

...
```

Comment: `[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]` I would start here. Do you use NSObject's `performSelector` somewhere in your app? It looks like you are trying to perform a selector that is not implemented for this particular object.

Comment: It is at pushplugin.m line 573; setApplicationBadgeNmber was invoked on an object that doesn't have that method.